# Fonts squashed in Area51 proposal descriptions

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51, design

Sorry, I don't know the technical terms.

[image]

(I see this in Firefox and Chrome)

Comment: The font name is "Impact".  Pretty descriptive name.

Comment: @Hans, what I am missing is the name for the 'droppy-down-bits' that you can't see :)

Comment: Descenders.  I see what you mean now.  Document your browser.  I see it too, just barely, on FF 3.6.13

Answer (score 1):

Overflow's set to `hidden` on the `.proposal-summary` elements, probably as a clearfix. Removing that, or adding a small bottom padding should fix this.

Comment: I just implemented this fix, and it seems to have fixed the problem.